# Laravel routes does not work

Tags: php, url, laravel-5, laravel-4, routes

when I write this `Route::get('/', 'Login@index');`

and use url

"http://localhost/laravel-4.2.11/blog/" it works,

but when I use this `Route::get('home', 'Login@index');`

and url "http://localhost/laravel-4.2.11/blog/home" it gives 404 error

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your route with a preceding `/`, like so:

`Route::get('/home', 'Login@index');`

While this isn't how it's documented, this works for me on a number of projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use both / and /home for homepage,

```
Route::get('/{home?}', 'Login@index');
```

Or you can write it into two,

```
Route::get('/', 'Login@index');
Route::get('home', 'Login@index');
```

Comment: it doesnt work if use this  `Route::get('home', 'Login@index');`

Comment: I mean you should keep the two Route::get('/', 'Login@index');
Route::get('home', 'Login@index');, not just one when you want to use Route::get('home', 'Login@index');

Comment: show the config for your project root dir, for example apache2's DocumentRoot

Answer (score 0):

***Frist***

You should check what do you have in the error log file, usually in

> storage/logs/laravel.log

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors

This should give you the information about why this URL can not find it.

***Second***

Please check the configuration on your web server:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation#web-server-configuration

**Apache**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

**Nginx**

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

***Third***

Please report the result of this test...